# Monitoring transactions for Solana in real time for an address

Tags: python, solana-py

So I wonna monitor an address or more to print in my terminal each time there's a transaction...

I used the solana-py library method

**signatures = client.get_signature_for_address(address, limit=1).value[0].signature**

and then

**client.get_transaction(signature, max_supported....=0)**

This seem not to detect transactions and if it does it only brings up failed transactions , is my approach not correct or there's some more stuff I need to do

**EDIT:**

from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

tkn_pub_key = Pubkey.from_string('DySLzKey6Aqwaydi3QgpauewUtKjURaAza4rJZxkznHN')
#get signatures
signatures = client.get_signatures_for_address(tkn_pub_key, limit=20).value[0].signature

tx_details = client.get_transaction(signatures, max_supported_transaction_version=0)

trx_meta = tx_details.value.transaction.meta

if trx_meta.inner_instructions and trx_meta.inner_instructions[0]:
print(tx_details.value.transaction.meta)

i enclose this in a while loop with 5seconds sleep time

Comment: A reproducible example would help answer this

Comment: from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

tkn_pub_key = Pubkey.from_string('DySLzKey6Aqwaydi3QgpauewUtKjURaAza4rJZxkznHN')
#get signatures
signatures = client.get_signatures_for_address(tkn_pub_key, limit=20).value[0].signature
tx_details = client.get_transaction(signatures, max_supported_transaction_version=0)
trx_meta = tx_details.value.transaction.meta
if trx_meta.inner_instructions and trx_meta.inner_instructions[0]:
    print(tx_details.value.transaction.meta)

Answer (score 2):

To preface this answer, I am employed by Helius.

Depending on how you are using this, you could use a combination of webhooks + https://tailscale.com/blog/tailscale-vscode/ which would allow you to get a domain for your localhost. I.e you could get the data streamlined to your terminal.

Check out Helius to setup a webhook for free here, and just paste in the URL produced from tailscale: https://dev.helius.xyz/dashboard/app